# JQmobi / Intel touch events dont work on Android Nexus phone

Tags: javascript, android, jqmobi

Im using JQmobi to create a mobile app, and it works perfectly fine in the browser, and in emulation mode for all phones.

However, when I actually upload the app to the server, and run it on my LG Nexus phone.
It loads, but it doesn't register any touch events such as swipe or click.

This might not really be the place to ask this....but I was just wondering if anyone else has experienced a similar issue, and maybe they found a fix?